# In GTK what is the difference between "signals" and "events"?

Tags: gtk, gobject

I am trying to get started with GTK, but I find the documentation for signals (https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/signal.html) hard to understand.

It seems as there is a difference between a "signal" and an "event".
For example, the documentation for the "event"-signal for a Widget (https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-event) says

> The GTK+ main loop will emit three signals for each GDK event delivered to a widget: one generic ::event signal, another, more specific, signal that matches the type of event delivered (e.g. “key-press-event”) and finally a generic “event-after” signal.

So it seems to me, that GDK uses "events", whereas GTK+ uses "signals". Maybe events are just packed into signals, or the other way around? Or are they completely different things?

My understanding of the above quote:
When a key is pressed, then a GDK-event is fired. This GDK-event calls a callback function of the widget (which is not for the programmer to interfer with). The callback function then in turn emits the three signals `::event`, `key-press-event` and `event-after`, one after the other. As a programmer I can intercept these signals by writing callback functions. If the callback for the first `::event` signal returns `TRUE`, then the second `key-press-event` signal is not fired, otherwise it is. The third `event-after` signal is always fired.

Is my understanding correct?

Furthermore, in the docs, sometimes signals are prepended by a double colon (`::event`) and sometimes they are not (`key-press-event` and `event-after`). What is the difference? What is the meaning of the double colon?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it's just nomenclature.

signals, in GObject, are just fancy ways to calling named lists of functions; each time an instance "emits" a signal, the GSignal machinery will look at all the callbacks connected to that particular signal, and call them sequentially until either one of these conditions is satisfied:

1. the list of callbacks is exhausted
2. the signal accumulator used when the signal is defined will stop the signal emission chain if a defined condition is met

all signals emitted by GDK or GTK+ (as well as any other GObject-based library) work exactly in that way.

events, in GDK, are structures related to windowing system events, like a button press, a key release, a pointer crossing the window boundaries, a change in the window hierarchy, and so on and so forth. the only interaction you generally have with GDK events happen in specific signals on the `GtkWidget` types. as a convention (though it does not always apply) the signals that have a `GdkEvent` structure have an `-event` suffix, like `button-press-event`, or `key-release-event`, or `enter-notify-event`, or `window-state-event`. again, those are GObject signals, and their only specialization is having a `GdkEvent` as an argument.

as for the double colon: the full specification of a signal is made of the type that declares it, e.g. `GtkWidget`, and the signal name, e.g. `button-press-event`, separated by a double colon, e.g. `GtkWidget::button-press-event`. the `::button-press-event` notation is just a documentation shorthand, signifying that the speaker is referring to the `button-press-event` signal.

Answer (score 3):

The simple way to understand it is that, events are something that you do to an object, say GtkButton (we choose button as something you can see). When you click a button, the button receive an event from you (actually it's from Gdk ( a thin layer between gtk and underlying window and graphics system ). Upon receive an event it has to do something. otherwise it's a dead object.

From there, something has to be done. Since an object has to do something, a signal will pick up the rest. Signal will emitted "from" the object to tell other object something has happened. Short word, signal is a catcher of an event.
The most used pre-defined signal for GtkButton is "clicked". Within the callback for the signal, you can do anything you want to be.

Now, another question, hey, why don't we just catch the event from the mouse button and do it from there? Of course you can. Here's how :

1. get the position of the button in the window
2. calculate the allocated width,height and position in memory, so when user emit event button press within the are, it will trigger something
3. make another function that when you resize, minimize, maximize the window, calculate again the position, width and height and keep it in memory. also every other widgets around it because their size is also change.
4. if you choose not to show the widget, calculate every widgets in a window because their position, width and height are totally different, store it in the memory.
5. if you move the window or window is hidden, don't do anything because the coordinate of the button is replaced by something else on top. you don't want to click the screen (to where the button was) and your application do something while other window is focused.
   6.if you loose your mouse ?................damn

Next, Gdk uses signals too. For example GdkScreen emits 3 signals, which react from an event: somehow you turn off the compositing window, somehow you hookup with other screen and somehow you change the screen resolution.

Next, callbacks are not emitted signals. Signal "emits" callbacks. It is up to you if you to  connect (intercept, in your term) or not. It is not your function, it's predefined function which you just wrap arounds it with your function name. After you use a signal, you can also disconnect it, for some reason.

Next, yes, if the widget signal "event" return True, the second specific signal is disconnected. Note: do not tamper with event mask of a widget, since a widget has its own default event masks.

Finally, double-colon? either its documenter like the double colon or just saying this signal belong to a class. Don't worry about it, you probably not going to use it in C